# add an image right after the total in the checkout page @shopify

Tags: image, shopify, liquid, checkout, shopify-template

I want to add an image right after the total price at the checkout page, look at the example:
[image]

I tried to add the img directly in the checkout.liquid in this section:
[image]

but that displays my image at the very bottom of the whole order-summary__section

update: I tried the suggested answer, but it didnt work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the Checkout.liquid you can add this in with a javascript function just target `.order-summary__section--total-lines` and insert your image after that element.

You can't add it in as liquid because as you've seen the whole order summary content area is contained in the `{{ content_for_order_summary }}` tag

````
      (() => {
      
        'use strict';
            
          const selectors = {
            targetTotalLines : '.order-summary__section--total-lines',
          };

          const injectImage = function() {
            let htmlContentToInject = `<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0177/9856/666/files/ICON.png?v=1663076456" />`;
            document.querySelector(selectors.targetTotalLines).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', htmlContentToInject);
          };

          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
            injectImage();
          });
      
      })()
    </script> ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qcNA.png
````

Comment: I already tried that, but it didnt work for me

Comment: You might need to work on this a bit more because it just did it quickly but it does work. Original comment updated

Comment: You should be aware that Shopify may update their checkout layout without notice which would break this.